# Field Recorders, Quality to Price, any hidden companies?

Tags: field-recorder, portable-recorder

I am in the middle of researching different field recorders.

Sound devices - £1400 for just 2 channels, twice that for 4 :(
Zaxcom - nomad is around £2500  slightly too much

Roland R44 - GREAT PRICE, but having to upgrade the pre amps seems a little backwards.

Tascam - again great price, but unsure of quality.

And I already own the Fostex Fr.

Are there any hidden companies? I'm not looking for a brand name, but something that will work, Inbuilt hard drive OR SD card capabilities. Semi decent battery life. 92k +, and 4 track (need to try future proof)

I would love to be able to get a sound devices as I know thats what everyone uses and loves, but 4 track suddenly makes it so darn expensive. unless theres a second hand market for these things I don't know of.

Really scratching my head over this :(

Anyways hope some guys n gals here can be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

Something you may want to consider is using a device like the Zoom H4N or the Marantz PMD661 as a recording device, and buying yourself some decent mic pres to drive the signal (rather than the device's built-in preamps). A Sound Devices MixPre would work well ahead of either of those devices. Or you could look into a piece of used, higher-end, gear like a Wendt X3 or X4. Just something to consider, as you'll always be able to use those preamps...no matter what recorder you work with in the future.

You need to take a look at how you plan to use this gear, and figure out which features are necessary vs. unnecessary. It's entirely possible that you can find some combination of gear that does exactly what you need for a lower cost. The higher end recorder/preamp devices (Sound Devices, Zaxcom, Aaton) are expensive because they include those esoteric/niche functions that certain people need. You may not be one of those people. Then again, you may...but at least you'll know you made the right decision for your needs.

Comment: Just a note - there are some fairly widely discussed issues (here and elsewhere) with plugging the tape out of the MixPre into the Zoom H4n. See other threads for details of this; it's related to the consumer-level line inputs of the Zoom, and necessitates in-line attenuation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tascam hdp2 could be a good choice, it's rated as "upper class" recorder in www.professional-audio.de

I will buy it and try it in the future, because i can't get the money for a SD in the next Years, i think

Comment: ...but it have just 2 mic chan. it soo weak. :/ i think simplier things better choice.
http://tascam.com/product/dr-100mkii/
http://www.olympusamerica.com/cpg_section/product.asp?product=1581
these are can record more than 2 chan, and the price is much lower!